# error when printing a page with css

Tags: javascript, html, css

The user has the chance to print current page from the website when clicking on an element from a menu:

```
<li>
  <a href="#" onClick="window.print()">
    <i class="icon-print"></i>
    Print Page
  </a>
</li>
```

The page has a table and in each row there is a button (obviosly with an inside link to redirect to another page).

The problem is that when previewing the page, those links on the page appears explicitly like this:

[image]

also the menu (javascript) is also displayed...

What can I do to fix this?

This is my **print.css**:

```
.header {
    display: none;
}

.page-sidebar {
    display: none;
}

.color-panel {
    display: none;
}

.hidden-print {
    display: none;
}

.footer {
    display: none;
}

.no-page-break {
    page-break-after: avoid;
}

.page-container {
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 0px;
}

.page-content {
    min-height: auto !important;
}

.breadcrumb {
    display: none;
}
```

Comment: in your `print.css`, add `.options { display: none; }`, assuming your "imprimir page" and other options are inside the class `options` and that you have a `print.css`.

Comment: Do you have a seperate css file for printing (media print)?

Comment: You said `The page has a table and in each row there is a button (obviosly with an inside link to redirect to another page).`, what's the id/class of it? You basically need to hide it.

Comment: @RononDex yes, i have added it to my question

Comment: @FranciscoPresencia here is the code for the button <td><a class="btn mini blue-stripe" href="{site_url()}admin/editFront/{$frontuser->id}">Modificar</a></td>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've been researching and found out that as the dropdown menu that i want to hide when printing is in a list, then i should use this:

```
.dropdown-menu li {
display: none;
}
```

and for hidding links:

```
a[href]:after {
content: none !important;
}
```

so now i got it right :)